# Origin of the term 'bastard sword'

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

In many computer games (usually role playing games), there is an item called a *bastard sword*.  Why is this name used, and does it bear any relation to the usual meaning of the term *bastard*?

Comment: There are several paragraphs in the english wikipedia covering the term bastard with respect to swords. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_sword Do you have something more specific in mind?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Originally, a "bastard sword" was another name for a [long sword](http://www.medieval-life-and-times.info/medieval-swords-and-armor/bastard-sword.htm), also known as a "hand and a half" sword. The sword is described as:

> Bastard swords often  had a more tapered, narrowly pointed blade. The Medieval Bastard Sword generally had a long handle which allowed for two-handed use and a longer blade. The Medieval Bastard Sword became popular due to is extreme reach and cutting and thrusting abilities and was predominantly used by the Medieval Knights.

The name "bastard sword" has its own explanation rooted in the French *epee batarde*. This term was born of confusion over how to categorize the weapon. From the same source:

> The versatility of the design prevented the sword from being specifically categorized as either a one-handed or two-handed weapon. *The word bastard was therefore to this sword meaning something irregular or inferior or of dubious origin, having a misleading appearance.*

Finally, this use of *bastard* does bear some relation to its usual definition, but not in the term of an illegitimate child. From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bastard):

> something that is spurious, irregular, inferior, or of questionable origin

Comment: Similarly a "bastard file" is one half way between a coarse file and a second cut file - ie. neither one thing nor the other.

Comment: And the typical bastard CHILD is often the product of a high-born father and a lower born mother, and is an irregular, suspect issue considered neither one nor the other, with a "misleading" pedigree.

Answer (score 7):

If you think about it as coming from French, it makes more sense. The word "batard" (with a ^ over the first a) is used much more liberally and less pejoratively in French. While it does mean an illegitimate child, in a more figurative sense, it carries the sense of something have a dual nature, which links back to the original meaning of coming from parents of two different socioeconomical classes. For example, there is a type of bread called a "batard," because it is half way between a baguette and a loaf. So, the aforementioned "epee batarde" is halfway between a long, two-handed sword and a short, one-handed sword.

Answer (score -1):

A [bastard sword](http://www.museumreplicas.com/p-763-german-bastard-sword.aspx) is also called as one handed sword and has a long blade.

Comment: But why is it 'bastard'?

Answer (score -1):

Several names of [bastard sword](http://www.bastardsword.net/) are:

1. Hand and Half Sword
2. Bastard Sword
3. épée bâtarde (French)
4. langes Schwert (German)

Comment: Although this information may be interesting and relevant, it doesn't actually answer the question. Answers should only be used to answer the question.

Comment: Note that "langes Schwert" just means "longsword" in German.