# Origin of current slang usage of the word 'sick' to mean 'great'?

Tags: etymology, slang, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How and why have some words changed to a complete opposite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22293/how-and-why-have-some-words-changed-to-a-complete-opposite)

How did 'sick' come to mean 'awesome' or 'really good / cool' in modern U.S. slang? I'm interested in origins and possibly regional patterns, if applicable.

This usage reminds me of the use of 'bad' to mean 'totally awesome' in the 80s. It would be interesting to know how that came about as well, and if the pattern is related...

Comment: I think the pattern **is** related, though I'm unable to substantiate that. Still, I've observed it enough: some adjective is used informally to mean something different than it typically means (maybe even the _opposite_ of what it usually means) – a _cool_ motorcycle, a _nasty_ curveball, a _rad(ical)_ dress, a _wicked_ dance move, a _gnarly_ book, an _epic_ sunset, a _sick_ jump, a _bad_ pizza, etc. Somehow, the word sticks for awhile, probably because it sounds innovative. Yet as the popularity of the word swells, its freshness wanes, and it becomes ripe to be displaced by something new.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of that prior question. This is much more specific.

Comment: Voted to re-open as this asks specifically about some words which are not specifically asked about or answered in the other one.

Comment: This question ought to be reopened, because the current answers are basically wrong.  Whether or not other usage in youth culture pre-dates it, *sick* became slang for pretty much the opposite of what it traditionally means in the late '90s in South London, with predominantly black kids into the 'grime' music scene, which in turn spawned the 'dubstep' music scene.  Dubstep has since become popular in the USA, and the American kids that use this word tend to be into dubstep, which originally comes from South London.  When I was a kid in the '80s, 'wicked' developed in very much the same way.

Comment: My favourite is how "dank", which means something like "damp, smelly and disgusting" came to have a positive meaning, because that's exactly what happened to "funky" decades earlier, which has a very similar meaning. (Probably, in both cases, because of cannabis).

Comment: I have a theory of the origin of "sick" as meaning "cool".
Older kids commented on disgusting or sickening situations. 
Peers or younger kids, wanting to be part of the in-group, understood this as a something in which they gained social capital, thus getting cool points. Over this kind of usage and misunderstandings of the original shocking sights commented upon, the word has come to mean "cool".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *OED* says this slang is now especially used for skateboarding and surfing, and the first quotation is from a 1983 *UNC-CH Campus Slang* by the University of North Carolina, Chapel Hill:

> Sick, unbelievably good: The Fleetwood Mac concert was sick.

[*The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA581&lpg=PA581&dq=%22sick%22%20etymology%20slang&source=bl&ots=cROsSVHXeq&sig=ODPHeRtAElhLUPZjFBA11Q-36Ak&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2AgIUIGxHOjT4QSs9MCLBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sick%22%20etymology%20slang&f=false) (2007) says:

> **bad** ***adj* 1** good; tough. *US*, 1897.
>
> **sick** ***adj*** ... **6** excellent; wonderful. On the principle that BAD means 'good' *US*.

Partridge notes *bad* is much older, and the OED gives the source as George Ade's story of a black shoeshine boy, *Pink Marsh : a story of the streets and town* (1897):

> She sutny fix up a pohk chop 'at's bad to eat.

It says its originally US slang and means something good or excellent, especially stylish or attractive. The later quotations trace its use through black and jazz slang (1928, 1955, 1959, 1971 and 1989) until more 'mainstream' use is noted in a US newspaper in 1995 and a UK book in 2006.

The *OED* has another similar meaning of *bad* which is originally African-American and used of a person who is so dangerous they inspire admiration, or impressively tough, or especially formidably skilled. The earliest quotation is from 1843 but only meaning dangerous or hostile without admiration. Their next earliest is in 1938 in a musical context, as are some of the others, and I can see some overlap of these meanings.

---

[*A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=tvRp1whVFUsC&pg=PA731&lpg=PA731&dq=%22sick%22%20etymology%20slang&source=bl&ots=gR6O9UWG4y&sig=QGvGuduM2hbYuFmaC6ujKzOOU4o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2AgIUIGxHOjT4QSs9MCLBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sick&f=false) (2002) gives a possibly unrelated term using *sick*, but it's somewhat similar:

> In *knock* (one) *sick*, to astound, 'flabbergast': coll.: - 1923 (Manchon).

Comment: Growing up as a skater we often used the term sick as a synonym for "crazy" as well .... as in "You're sick in the head because you did that trick", but it was used to indicate approval.

Answer (score 5):

I think it was originally a skateboarding slang to express "shock and awe" after seeing something cool. I'm hazarding a guess that it was first used to describe crashes. The only corroboration I can find is from [About.com](http://skateboard.about.com/od/skateboardingdictionary/a/Skateboard_Slang.htm) and a [Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-72813.html) forum post. Quoting the latter:

> I first heard the word "sick" being used as slang on the 1987
>   skateboarding video put out by Powell and Peralta entitled "The Search
>   for Animal Chin." A skater did some cool trick or whatever, and a
>   hardcore skateboarder onlooker said, "that's sick". We thought it was
>   hilarious, and I have heard it used ever since, though mainly among
>   skaters/surfers/snowboarders/druggies and the like.
>
> It is my observation that the word not so much means "cool", but
>   carries a connotation more extreme than just that. It is used to
>   describe something that is unbelievable, unprecedented, or just plain
>   mind-blowing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a form of "reverse psychology," in which words like "disruptive" took on positive connotations, around, or just before the turn of the century.

[Could "bastard" have a positive connotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74099/could-bastard-have-a-positive-connotation/74200#74200)

Meaning that other words that normally have negative connotations, actually became "backhanded compliments" when used somewhat sarcastically.

Answer (score 0):

The association came from the ever present desire for greater kicks with entertainment, always pushing the limit. fun = fun –> wild = fun –> wilder = more fun –> etc.

I believe the expression came with the rock bands and their desire to push "wild", eg. when Alice Cooper killed a chicken (the chicken didn't actually die) on stage, outsiders and parents thought it was sickening, but the audience found it cool, and so fans of the rock scene adopted/coined the term "sick" meaning "wild", "cool", "awesome" – later to be included in more mainstream language.

note: I'm not saying "sick" necessarily came out of that one event, but rather out of the rock scene wanting to discover new ground, Alice Cooper, KISS, Rocky Horror Show, etc.