# 'This is so sick'

Tags: vocabulary

> 'This is so sick!'

What does this expression (usually said in a very anger manner) mean?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75017/origin-of-current-slang-usage-of-the-word-sick-to-mean-great

Answer (score 2):

If it is said with a very negative tone, this phrase means that the thing being referred to is 'sickening'.  Without further context I cannot say for certain, but it is very likely that the thing being referred to makes the person 'sick' in the sense that it is a groteque thing that they do not like.

It also can mean "very cool" as a slang term.  So you must judge the meaning based on the context and the intent of the indivudal speaking.

Comment: +1 I concur.  A less idiomatic way to make the same statement would be to say that something is [perverse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perverse) - wrong or different in a way that others feel is strange or offensive.

Answer (score 1):

The teenagers I coach say "This is so sick" all the time.  It can mean a few different things and can range from "This is really cool" to "Coach is a bastard for making me run this much".  Would need more context to tell where in the range yours falls.

Comment: He did mention "said in a very angry manner", so I think we can rule out the teenage slang for "very cool".  Though it is definitely worth noting that it is an expression that sometimes means that very thing.

Comment: @Zibbobz - I understand what you are saying but if someone is not familiar with this slang phrase then it often seems like they are angry.  It is often said in an excited or levitated way so I could see it coming off as angry.

Comment: Fair enough....though it's also possible they really are sick because of the situation they're experiencing.  As such, I think it IS important to mention both possibilites.